# Armazenar saída de script PHP em HTML "compactado"

Tags: php

Em um gerenciador de conteúdo, eu costumo gerar páginas estáticas em HTML cada vez que elas são visitadas, o script refaz o HTML quando há alguma alteração nessa página, simplesmente deletando o arquivo gerado anteriormente.

Quando o usuário visita essa página através do navegador, é servida a versão em HTML, isto é, o script verifica se existe algum HTML já criado, se sim então o mesmo é incluso e a execução termina sem realizar nenhuma consulta ou processamento de rotina, se não, ele faz todo o processamento e salva um HTML para ser servido posteriormente (como um cache).

A minha dúvida é saber se posso fazer isso utilizando um HTML compactado, utilizando a função `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')` ao invés de apenas ob_start();

Há algum problema de compatibilidade, ou talvez tenha algum método melhor para fazer o que preciso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma forma de compactação alternativa:

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {

    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',  // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
        '/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
    );

    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}

ob_start("sanitize_output")
```

Pergunta original:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225351/how-to-minify-php-page-html-output