# Como compactar a saída de um HTML em Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Eu respondi essa pergunta aqui uma vez tratando sobre o assunto:

[Armazenar saída de script PHP em HTML "compactado"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102317/armazenar-sa%C3%ADda-de-script-php-em-html-compactado).

Mas agora gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso em Laravel.

Quando se tratar de uma resposta HTML, como eu poderia capturar toda a renderização das views, antes de ser enviada ao navegador, e respondê-la compactada?

Aonde eu poderia definir isso no Laravel 5?

Na resposta acima já tem a solução de como compactar, porém eu gostaria de saber onde eu efetuaria essa ação no Laravel, da maneira mais apropriada, para tratar o conteúdo que vai para saída de dados, antes de ir para o cliente (navegador)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supondo que use o Laravel 5.2 você pode usar o método [`render`](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/View/View.html#method_render), então no Controller ficaria algo como, isto é um exemplo apenas para mostrar como usa-lo, eu troquei o conteudo de $data por uma nova saída com o `return`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        $v = view('welcome')->render(function ($obj, $data) {
            return 'Hello world!';
        });

        return $v;
    }
}
```

Então basta combinar ao outro código de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102364/3635 ficando algo como:

```
function reduzirHtml($data)
{
    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',  // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
        '/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
    );

    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );

    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $data);
}

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        return view('welcome')->render(function ($obj, $data) {
             return reduzirHtml($data);
        });
    }

    public function about()
    {
        return view('welcome')->render(function ($obj, $data) {
             return reduzirHtml($data);
        });
    }
}
```

Se mudar a função para `function reduzirHtml($obj, $data)` pode chamar diretamente:

```
return view('welcome')->render("\\App\\Http\\Controllers\\reduzirHtml");
```

Ou pode até mover a função `reduzirHtml` para um arquivo ou método em uma classe e chama-la como no exemplo:

```
//Função
return view('welcome')->render("\\reduzirHtml");

//Classe
return view('welcome')->render("\\Namespace\\Classe\\reduzirHtml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Para capturar todas as saída HTML da aplicação, você também pode utilizar um `Middleware`, que se encarregará de fazer esse pré-processamento.

Primeiro rode o comando:

```
 php artisan make:middleware HtmlCompressor
```

Em seguida, deixe o método `handle` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

/**
 * 
 * @author Wallace de Souza Vizerra <wallacemaxters@gmail.com>
 * 
 * */
class HtmlCompressor
{

    public function handle()
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        // Verifica se a saída é HTML

        if (str_contains($response->headers->get('content-type'), 'text/html')) {

            $search = [
                '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
                '/[^\S ]+\</s',  // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
                '/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
            ];

            $replace = [
                '>',
                '<',
                '\\1'
            ];

            $response->setContent(preg_replace($search, $replace, $response->getContent()));

            return $response;

        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Na classe `App\Http\Kernel` da sua aplicação, você vai adicionar esse middewlare que nós criamos na propriedade `$middleware`:

```
protected $middleware = [
   // outros middlewares
   \App\Http\Middleware\HtmlCompressor
];
```

Comment: Eu marcaria esta como a correta, pois ela é mais smart, quero dizer ela detecta se a saída é realmente html e ainda por cima fica organizado em um arquivo separado e ao mesmo tempo é automatizada.

Comment: Sua resposta tá boa sim. Eu só respondi com alternativa de um "tratamento global"

Comment: Eu sei :) ... só quis dizer que a sua por ser mais smart é a melhor alternativa, mas não quer dizer que a minha é ruim. O problema da minha resposta é quem usar ela, a coisa fica meio "solta", um usuário com menos experiencia provavelmente acabaria por desorganizar as coisas ou até replicar várias a função, isso por inexperiência mesmo ;)